# How to return synchronous result to asynchronous function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In Node 13, an external 3rd party library calls my code:

```
const myInput = myCode.run(somVar); // it doesn't use await
```

As my code then has to perform nested synchronous calls, how could I provide an appropriate return value to the 3rd party library that is not a promise, but the result of my promises?  Ideally something like this:

```
const run = (inputVar) =>{
   let result
   (async ()=>{  
      result = await doSyncCalls(inputVar);
   })(); // code should not proceed until after await
   return result;
} // will return undefined, but ideally should return doSyncCalls result
```

`deasync` would be a good solution, except it has an unresolved bug that causes nested promises to not resolve.

Comment: You can't do it. By definition, asynchronous functions return immediately, before the result is determined.

Comment: Making async code synchronous seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but @Barmar seems right. Synchronous code is going to block the event event loop - so there's going to be no way for the async function to actually resolve before the (synchronous) function that calls it resolves.

Comment: @dwjohnston - instead of saying it is a wrong solution, why not rather provide a solution [I'm unable to change the 3rd party library]

Comment: @Barmar: if you are right, then that is a significant weakness as one has little control over 3rd party libraries and it means we have a problem that Node and JS is unable to solve.

Comment: @Barmar none of the solutions proposed in the duplicate question answer my question.

Comment: That's because you can't do what you want. It's impossible to return a value from an asynchronous function.

Comment: @Barmar - it's not impossible deasync does it

Comment: That's because deasync hooks into the JavaScript engine using C code, it's not ordinary JavaScript.

Comment: And as you pointed out in the question, it doesn't work fully.

Comment: @Barmar - true it doesn't fully work, but perhaps someone smarter than us will come along with a solution?

Comment: I've reopened the question so it won't be ignored. But if someone actually has a solution, it should be added to the linked question, since that's where most searches will end up.

Comment: You have to use busy-wait approach, which is not an appropriate one.

Comment: Well, if you're willing to block your entire node.js process during this asynchronous operation (which is essentially what you're asking to do), then you can use a synchronous child_process function such as `execFileSync()` to synchronously run another app that executes your asynchronous operation, gets the result and returns it.  I've seem this proposed before as the only way to turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous operation, but I've never seen it actually be a good design choice.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right, "Busy-Wait" approach will not work in Javascript. Thank you.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes thanks that would work, for sync calls that use execFileSync().

Comment: FYI, another approach if you can know ahead of time what data the 3rd party API is going to ask you to get (or all possible things it might ask for) is to fetch the data asycnhronously BEFORE you call the 3rd party API so then when it calls you back, you already have the data stored in some local cache and can return it synchronously.

Comment: @jfriend00 - good suggestion, but I don't know - so I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Hmmm.  By your edit, you're showing the same `someVar` that you pass in to the original call that comes back to your callback.  If that's really the case, then you could fetch the value you need using that `someVar` BEFORE calling the API and put it in some cache so then you have it available synchronously when the callback gets called later.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I've edited it again to clarify - sorry for the confusion.  I'm unable to fetch the value before the call.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no way to synchronously return (from the callback) a value that you obtain asynchronously within the callback.  Javascript does not currently support that.  So, these are your options:

1. Put the asynchronous code in a child_process.  Then run that child process with something like `child_process.execFileSync()`.  That allows you to run the asynchronous code in the child process, but have the parent process block and wait for the result.  This is a hack because it blocks the parent while waiting for the result.  But, it can be made to work.
2. Before calling the library function, prefetch whatever value it is you will need when the callback is called.  This allows you to use regular asynchronous programming before you call the library and then once you have the desired value in some sort of cache, you can then call the 3rd party library and when it calls you back and wants the value, you will have it synchronously in a cache somewhere.  Obviously, this only works if you can figure what value or range of possible values will be required in the callback so you can pre-fetch them.
3. Modify the code in the library to add support for an asycnhronous callback.
4. Redesign code to work a different way that doesn't require this library or that can use some other library that doesn't have this problem.
5. Write or find some native code add-on (like `deasync`) that lets you block somehow during the asynchronous operation while still letting the event queue do what it needs to do to process the asynchronous completion.  This would have to hook deep into the internals of the V8 engine.  Or fix, `deasync` so it works for your case.
6. Write a blocking add-on in native code that could carry out your asynchronous operation in native code while blocking the V8 engine.

FYI, since everything but #2, #3 and #4 all block the main JS thread which is generally a bad thing to do in any server environment, and you've said that #2 was not practical, my preference would be #3 or #4.  Since you don't share the actual code and actual detailed library and problem, we can't help you with any specifics.

Probably the most straightforward solution to implement is #1 (package the code up into a child process that you run synchronously), but it blocks the app while running which is a downside.

Comment: Thank you jfriend00 - those are all great suggestions.  I'm still struggling with this and will revert once I've proven one of your suggestions or something else.